# Limit LDAP information for Domain User

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I want to configure LDAP address in Outlook, but what happens that after configuring in outlook all information in LDAP can be seen by the User.

Is there any way to limit LDAP information in Outlook?

Such as :-

1) No information related to disable user.

2) No information related to some high privilege user

3) No displaying of Phone number. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a Sepearate OU and name them Contact. and in that Create Only Contact Object for all of your Domain User, as per your requirement.

and while confiuguring LDAP address book in Outlook or any other E-mail client. Enter your search DN or Base DN as " OU=contact,DC=corp,DC=abc,DC=com " 
Here corp.abc.com is an example of your Domain name.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly revoke read access to all required properties from MMC AD snapin (using delegate control wizard), but don't do it.\

LDAP is designed to provide such information for authorized users.Why revoke it?

Anybody from domain can query same info user explorer's "Search in AD" function or by running

```
rundll32 dsquery.dll,OpenQueryWindow
```

When you mess-up permission on OUs and user-objects, you may have a big trouble.

Did you create dedicated user for outlook address book setup, or you are using integrated auth?

**UPDATE:**

Until you use integrated auth, you will need to revoke "Read attributes" and "Read Extended attributes" privileges on all user object in your OU from all users in that ou.

http://www.activewin.com/win2000/step_by_step/active_directory/delegsteps.shtml

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.rkosegi. well, i had not created any dedicated user for Outlook address book, so that mean i am using integrated auth. Awaiting your reply

Comment: Adding support for the "don't do it" statement.